# How to compare two files that are partially matching and replace the parts that are matching in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have 2 dat files, **FILE1** and **FILE2**. The first one has (for example) 1000 lines and the second 100 lines. The lines in both files have the same format, i.e. 5 numbers, separated by space. The lines with the values of **FILE2** are partially matching the lines from **FILE1**. For example, there is a line in **FILE2** that is:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

and there is a line in **FILE1** that is:

```
1 2 3 9 5
```

It is always the 4th value that is not matching. 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 5th values are always match. I want to do this in a bash script. I have started  this script so far.

```
#! /bin/bash

#USAGE: sh ./script.sh test.dat check.dat

 TEST_FILE=$1
 CHECK_FILE=$2
## for each line in TEST_FILE
 while read line ; do

 arr=$(echo $line | tr " " "\n")
 part_match=$(echo ${arr:0:8})
 X=$(grep "$part_match" ${CHECK_FILE})

## So up to here, if the partial match exists in FILE2, I save the line in X.
## Then I try to substitute them with awk or sed but none of them works.

 awk '{gsub(/${X}/, "${line}")}' check.dat > check_new.dat
## OR
 sed -i "s/$X/$line/pw" check.dat

done < ${TEST_FILE}
```

None of them works. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: How does the 5th value match, 5 == 6? Also, what do you mean by "I want to this"?

Answer (score 0):

"if the partial match exists in file 2" - based on `0:8`, if you have a partial match, you will have a full match, because that will include the 4th digit.

If you want to match on the first 3 digits, then you should be using `0:6`.

The sed command is also not correct - either remove the `w` flag or specify a file name. To edit the original check.dat in place:

```
sed -i "s/$X/$line/p" check.dat
```

OR, to write the change to check_new.dat, keeping as is check.dat

```
sed "s/$X/$line/pwcheck_new.dat" check.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue!

```
 awk '{key=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $5} FNR==NR{a[key];next} key in a{print}' shortfile longfile
```

will print the matching lines in longfile.  It's not clear what you want to do with this info though.